# Sending Message to ActiveMQ Topic Using AJAX (amq.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, activemq-classic, messaging

I am using JavaScript library i.e. amq.js for sending/receiving messages to a Topic on ActiveMQ.
I am successfully been able to listen the messages published on a particular topic and process them using

```
amq.addListener("test", "topic://foo", myHandler.rcvMessage);
```

from amq.js.
I need to send a message using amq.js, the message is filled in the AMQ Gui as follows:

[image: The message to be sent using JavaScript]

How should I compose this message shown in above screenshot so that it can be sent via JavaScript/AJAX using following method:

```
amq.sendMessage("topic://Connector1",myMessage);
```

By default the sendMessage() method works as follows:

```
sendMessage : function(destination, message, type, header) {// type and header are added manually
            sendJmsMessage(destination, message, 'send');
                        //sendJmsMessage(destination, message, type);
        },
```

I edited the fixed 'send' part and tried to add value of Type given in screenshot, but it seems to throw an error. Below are the values passed to the method:

```
destination : "topic://Connector1"
message     : "12345,6789"
type        : 'send'  OR "SayHello#12345"
```

I guess I need to compose a message in some other format, any help or guidance is welcomed.

Comment: I think you want to put the various values from the web console screenshot into the `headers` object that is an argument to `sendJmsMessage()`.

Comment: thanks for the reply' let me try that.

Comment: Did putting your headers into the `headers` object get it working?

Comment: no' it is not working, i have tried putting a number of headers, taken from the request header from AMQ management gui message sender.